# How to find inverse function of function with parameter?

Tags: functions, parametric, inverse-function

I'm trying to find the inverse function of this function:
$$
f_a(x) = \frac{x^a}{x^a + (1-x)^a}
$$

- $a$ - parameter
- $x$ - variable

Is it possible to find if there is a parameter here?
Hope for your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: $a$ is the parameter here

Comment: The expression is not invertible for all values of $a$, for example $a=4$ presents trouble. You have two solutions for $f_4(x) = \frac{3}{4}$, for example.

Comment: I think it's not invertible of every even number for $a$ ($\ldots, -4,-2,0,2,4,\ldots$). Otherwise you just can solve $y=f_a(x)$ for $x$.

Comment: @MattiP., okay, but what about this function but with parameter equal to 2.5? I have checked online inverse function finders, they can't solve it, but they can solve if parameter equal to 2. It's good acceleration function with ranges [0;1], I want to use it in my program, but I need to find its inverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}
f_a\circ f_b(x)=\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{x^b}{\cancel{x^b+(1-x)^b}}\right)^a}{\left(\dfrac{x^b}{\cancel{x^b+(1-x)^b}}\right)^a+\left(1-\dfrac{x^b}{\cancel{x^b+(1-x)^b}}\right)^a}\\
=\dfrac{x^{ab}}{x^{ab}+(\cancel{x^b}+(1-x)^b-\cancel{x^b})^a}\\
=\dfrac{x^{ab}}{x^{ab}+(1-x)^{ab}}
=f_{ab}(x)$$

> So we have $\quad f_a\circ f_b = f_{ab}$

You can verify that since $f_1(x)=\dfrac{x}{x+(1-x)}=x$ then $f_a^{-1}=f_{\frac 1a}$

Answer (score 0):

$$f_a(x) = \frac{x^a}{x^a + (1-x)^a} \implies \frac 1{f_a(x)}=1+\frac{(1-x)^a } {x^a}\implies $$ $$\frac 1{f_a(x)}-1=\Bigg[\frac {1-x}x\Bigg]^a\implies\Bigg[\frac 1{f_a(x)}-1\Bigg]^{\frac 1a}=\frac {1-x}x\implies x=???$$

Answer (score 0):

On the domain you mentioned $(0,1)$, I think you just need to invert the parameter $a$ itself, and it works.
$$f^{-1}_a(x) = \frac{x^\frac{1}{a}}{x^\frac{1}{a} + (1-x)^\frac{1}{a}}$$